# Getting another users email address in Facebook app

Tags: facebook, email, permissions

Am developing a system for an app to award points users for recruiting their friends. When the friend accepts the request I can retrieve the id of the person who invited them but can not find their email.

Have tried:

```
    $fbInviter = $facebook->api("/$inviterId", 'GET');
    $fbInvEmail = $fbInviter['email'];
```

but it appears ['email'] isn't in the returned array.
The app requests permission from each user when the first access it aswell as requesting offline access so permissions shouldn't be a problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the email address for a Facebook user other than the current user, and the current user's address is only available if they've granted you the `email` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)